# Have there been any examples of 'advanced' technology used for fetal medicine in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek

I haven't seen all episode of all the shows, nor have I read all the books, so I wasn't able to answer this myself.  But has there been any advancements shown in any of the alpha or beta canon of *Star Trek* regarding Fetal Medicine?  Like instead of ultrasounds, are there holograms? Is there more advanced monitoring, Are C-Sections performed via transporter?

I remember in *Star Trek*(2009) when they show Kirk's birth, they don't really show anything with regards to technology, but surely they've covered a few pregnancies over the past 50+ years of *Star Trek*

Comment: From the Vault of *Things CBredlow Thinks on His Daily Commute*

Comment: Here's a list of episodes involving pregnancy: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Pregnancy#List_of_pregnancies

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for that list, I was more curious about any examples of new stuff used.

Comment: Kirk's mom seems to have some sort of wireless baby monitor things on her in the reboot film

Comment: @Valorum that's something that exists now, so I didn't include that

Comment: @CBredlow: I figured that, at the least, it gives people references to start from. ^_^

Comment: McCoy didn't need anything fancy to help birth that baby in TOS, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooypmDJX4k8  He did use that spinny medical thing though.

Comment: In "Deadlock," a fetal transport is performed on Samantha Wildman's baby. This isn't really "medicine," but rather a medical procedure.

Comment: @HamSandwich by "medicine" I mean medical science

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Most of the advancements you mentioned were seen in Voyager.

In [Deadlock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deadlock_(episode)) the Doctor performed a c-section by transporter for Naomi Wildman, because her cranial ridges would have been hazardous to her mother, Samantha, in a normal delivery.

In [Lineage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lineage_(episode)) a holographic representation of Miral Paris is created from her DNA.

[image: Miral Paris hologram]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I haven’t seen much of voyager yet

Comment: See also the 29th century Borg maturation chamber from Drones.

Comment: Calling that a c-section may be a bit of a stretch, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper True. "Fetal removal" would be more accurate I guess.

Answer (score 18):

I believe that transporter technology has sometimes been used to transfer fetuses from one womb to another.  I don't remember which episode or episodes I might have seen it in, and there are about 800 episodes to choose from.

In Deep Space Nine "Body Parts" the fetus of Kirayoshi O'Brien is transferred from his Mother Keiko to his surrogate mother Kira after Keiko is injured.  But the dialog doesn't say how Dr. Bashir did it.

> BASHIR: Kira almost had us clear of the asteroid field, and then the deflectors became overwhelmed. We were side-swiped by a rock the size of this room. A fuel pod exploded and Keiko was thrown against the bulkhead. She had a concussion, broken ribs, internal haemorrhaging. I managed to stabilise her but the baby's autonomic functions were failing. I had to find another womb for the baby, and the only two people available were Major Kira and me.
>
> SISKO: I think you made the right choice, Doctor.
>
> O'BRIEN: But the Major's Bajoran. How can she carry a human child?
>
> BASHIR: I had to stimulate Kira's estrogen and progesterone production, and administer high doses of tesokine to enable the baby to metabolise Bajoran nutrients.
>
> SISKO: But the bottom line is it worked, right?
>
> BASHIR: Right.
>
> O'BRIEN: So, when will Keiko will be strong enough to take the baby back?
>
> BASHIR: Well, Keiko should be up on her feet in a day or two. However, the baby
>
> O'BRIEN: What?
>
> BASHIR: Major Kira will have to carry the baby to term. You see, Chief, Bajoran women carry their children for less than five months. Because they have such a short gestation period, they vascularise very quickly. Mother and child form a complex interconnecting network of blood vessels. In order to transfer the baby back to Keiko, I would have to sever those ties, which would likely cause massive internal haemorrhage in Kira and a severe respiratory trauma for the baby.
>
> O'BRIEN: So, what you're telling me is that Major Kira's going to have my baby?

This doesn't actually  say that Dr. Bashir used a transporter to move Kirayoshi from one womb to another, but the way he adjusted the body chemistry so that a woman could bear a child of another species seems like very advanced medicine.

Comment: Fun aside - IIRC, this story was written to accommodate Nana Visitor's actual pregnancy. You can only have an actor stand behind sofas and command consoles so often...

Comment: _"BASHIR: [..] The only two people available were Major Kira and me. / SISKO: I think you made the right choice, Doctor."_ Hehe.

Answer (score 16):

In "[The Child](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Child_(episode)#Act_One)", episode 2x1 of *Star Trek: The Next Generation", at the very least, their imaging technology seems to be very advanced, giving a view of the developing child that would require surgery in our time, although we still only see a flat image:

[image: Pulaski displays the developing child in Troi]

Answer (score 0):

In the Voyager episode "Collective" they come across a group of children Borg and one of them is a little baby that gets returned to the Borg Collective. As the baby was a newborn and already had functioning implants I assume the Borg must have some kind of fetal medicine to assimilate the fetus in utero (but perhaps it is done immediately upon birth). [Baby Borg](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Borg_baby.jpg)

Comment: They do have maturation chambers, as seen [here](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Maturation_chamber?file=Borg_nursery_2376.jpg) and [here](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Maturation_chamber?file=Borg_nursery.jpg).